# How to get value of button onclick in list.item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, button, onclick

I can't get value of a button when onclick. When I console.log BikeID nothing happens and the button doesn't seem to know the value of the List.item. I am trying to get the button to understand what ID it is "connected" to.

This is for a rental system, running MySQL and PHP. I've tried different buttons, inputs, and variations.

...

```
<List>
{this.bikes.map(bike => (
   <List.Item key={bike.BikeID}>
       {bike.BikeID} - {bike.Status} , {bike.Information}''
         <Button.Success value={bike.BikeID} onClick={e =>(this.BikeID = e.target.BikeID)} onChange={this.move}> Move to Status 1 </Button.Success>
          </List.Item>
        ))}
      </List>
```

...

```
move() {
  console.log(this.BikeID);
  bikeService.moveBike(this.BikeID, bikes => {
  this.bikes = bikes;
});
  setTimeout(() => {}, 250);
}
```

...

Expected results is that the button can detect what List.Item (and which BikeID) it belongs to.

Comment: I think you are looking for `this.BikeID = bike.BikeID`

Comment: Where should I put it?

Comment: at `onclick` instead of `this.BikeID = e.target.BikeID`

Comment: The console.log said "Cannot read property 'BikeID' of undefined" when I kept the "e" and only changed target. And when I only have {this.BikeID = bike.BikeID} , I got a warning for "Expected 'onClick'. ???

Answer (score 0):

there are different solutions with different pros and cons. It also depends on your Button.Success component.

Im not sure what you have in mind with the onChange and how the Button component handle clicks

```
//add a constructor to your component
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  //add this context to the move function to access this.bikes
  this.move = this.move.bind(this);
}
move(e) {
  let bikeId = e.target.value;
  let bikes = this.bikes;
  // ... do whatever you have to do with bikeId and bikes
}

render() {
  //...
  <Button.Success value={bike.BikeID} onClick={this.move}> Move to Status 1 </Button.Success>
  //...
}
```

other solution can be: the Button component could read the e.target.value and pass it back to the onClick method (this.move).